# Scroll snapping on tailwind css doesn't work on next js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

so in the index.tsx i've put a className "snap-y" on the root div and a "snap-center" on its children (section) but it doesn't seem to work when i followed what the docs says

here'es the code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Hero from '../components/Hero'
import About from '../components/About'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-[#fff] snap-y snap-mandatory '>
      <Head>
        <title>Portfolio | name</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <section className='snap-center'>
        <Hero/> 
      </section>

      <section className='snap-center'>
        <About/>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tried doing what the docs said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set fixed height, width and overflow-scroll for parent wrapper

```
  <div className='bg-[#fff] snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen overflow-scroll'>
      <section className='snap-center'>
        <Hero/> 
      </section>
      <section className='snap-center'>
        <About/>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: EDIT:   I fixed it by using overflow-x-hidden instead of overflow-scroll and it still worked


||||    *another follow -up question*

although your solution did work ,somehow a horizontal scrollbar appeared, can we do something to remove it?

Comment: try overflow-y-scroll instead of overflow-x-hidden